# bootstrap modal strange behavior : only overlay on all page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use compliled version of bootstrap 3.3.2 for a gallery project.
The json file of my compiled version of boostrap can be visited here : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=708118d9dd92604683a8

I want to display some informations in a modal, but it doesn't work well.
I use code example here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples and my page can be visited here : http://test.vincentbourganel.fr/20140629-vacances-ete-corse/_mg_1281.jpg.html (the modal is on the "i" icon).

When modal is opened **an overlay freeze all the screen (the content of modal is not accessible)**.

Can you help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your modal overlay overlap modal content. Here is quick fix with increasing modal `z-index`:

```
.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1040;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fix with Bootstrap 3.3.4.